# v5: Has CallbackInstrument been removed along with other PolyphonicNodes?

Tags: audiokit

I noticed in the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/v5-main/docs/MigrationGuide.md) that polyphonic nodes have been removed. Does this also apply to CallbackInstrument? Is it still the case?

> The oscillator banks such as AKOscillatorBank have all been removed. They were coded in a way that we have since outgrown. The only polyphonic node left is Synth but we intend on bringing back polyphonic instruments in a well-coded way as soon as possible.

I'm trying to build a Sequencer which uses CallbackInstrument to drive UI updates. I've not been able to get the callback to work so far. I'm not sure if the problem is with my code or CallbackInstrument hasn't been fully implemented in v5 yet.